# Ellipsis with a "transferred" word

Tags: ellipsis

Noticed a curious usage in the White Stripes song "We're Going to be Friends"; I know I've seen it before but can't think of another example. The line is

"Teacher marks our height against the wall."

Strictly speaking, "against" is not the right preposition there. If the teacher wanted, say, to compare our height-against-the-wall, our height-in-the-middle-of-the-room, our height-outside, etc., then it might be the right preposition.

What we actually have here is the picture of kids standing *against* the wall and the teacher measuring (perhaps by also holding a tape measure *against* the wall) and then marking their height *on* the wall. By using "against," the part of the picture that isn't specifically described is suggested. In a sense, the preposition "against" is transferred, so to speak, form the bit that was elided.

No big question here, just a curiosity. Thinking that the examples I can't quite call to mind involved maybe an adjective or a verb, something with more conventional descriptive content than a preposition. I think there must be cases where more work is done by the word that has been "smuggled in" than here, where we could fill in the rest just from cultural knowledge. (It does enable a certain desirable compression in the lyric, which is also curious.) Maybe arguments with suppressed premises. Maybe a rhetorical technique.

Comment: The phenomenon you describe is interesting, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: There's no ellipsis here: the PP is a secondary complement on the pronoun *us*, which is implicit (and arguably explicit) in the determinative *our*.

Comment: @lemontree I hoped to see other cases where a phrase or clause had been suppressed/elided but its content suggested by "smuggling" in a word from it, where there's a syntactic opportunity, in this case, using the prep "against" instead of "on." I thought of it as a way the speaker can sort of coax implicature, if you see what I mean.

Comment: @StonryB I would agree if the verb were "recorded" or "measured" or something, but because it is "marked," I think it's more natural to take the PP as telling us where the marks were made.

Comment: One more try: If we read "We stood against the wall and the teacher marked our height," we would take "on the wall" as implied at the end of the sentence. In Jack White's line, "against the wall" gets to be both at once. (I suspect neither he nor most listeners even notice that "against" is the "wrong" preposition.)

Comment: Classic example: A and B are originally seeing each other, and let's say A is a girl. A: I'm leaving you. B: Who is he? Here we have a normally anaphoric 'he' without an explicit antecedent.

Comment: This sounds more like a language specific question (if there is any question at all here). You may want to edit and resubmit on https://english.stackexchange.com . Also, poetry (including song lyrics) can have a looser connection to the usual patterns of a language so hard to judge 'correctness' (and so is usually considered off-topic on ELU)